# PHP login system with admin and users

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I want to make a log-in form with a difference between user and administrator. So, user goes to page /123 and admin goes to page /456. I tried a lot, but it doesn't work. Here is my:

**register.php**

```
<html>

<?php

//$submitbutton = $_GET['submit'];

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{

ob_start();
$host="localhost";
$DB_username="....";
$DB_password="...";
$db_name="m6-biol";
$tbl_name="leden";

$connection = mysql_connect("$host", "$DB_username", "$DB_password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


    $username   = $_POST['username'];
    $email  = $_POST['email'];
    $password   = $_POST['password'];

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // Validate email address
    {
        $message =  "Wrong e-mail ";
    }

    $query = "SELECT email FROM leden WHERE email ='".$email."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    $numResults = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($numResults>=1)
    {
        $message = $email." Email already exist";
    }
    else
    {
        mysql_query("insert into leden(username,email,password) values('".$username."','".$email."','".md5($password)."')") or die (mysql_error());;
        $message = "You are a member";
    }
    echo $message;
//  }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <p><input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Name"></p>
    <p><input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email"></p>
    <p><input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input name="action" type="hidden" value="signup" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Signup" name="submit" /></p>
 </form>

 </html>
```

**controle.php (means in Dutch config.php)**

```
    <?php
ob_start();
$host="localhost";
$DB_username="******";
$DB_password="******";
$db_name="m6-biol";
$tbl_name="leden";

$connection = mysql_connect("$host", "$DB_username", "$DB_password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=md5($_POST['password']); 

//$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
//$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=($result ? mysql_num_rows($result) : 0);

if($count==1){
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword"); 
    header("location:gelukt.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong username or password\n";
}

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Comment: whatever tutorial you're following, its *way* out of date. Try over [here](http://www.phptherightway.com/)

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** do this. Throw this code out before you make a mess of things. You should be using a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that comes with a built-in [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) because writing your own is not something you want to be doing. If you're not able to [properly secure a PHP application](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) then I **strongly** encourage you to use a pre-existing library to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to start using session:

```
session_start()
```

And change:

```
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
```

use it
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

```
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $array['username'];
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $array['password'];
```

I have helped

Answer (score -1):

a few things to make your PHP code "better".

1. DO NOT use mysql_functions it is no longer maintained.  Instead, use [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or

[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

2. you are using correctly the real escape string but change it mysqli_ or PDO like I said.. initializing it only once is enough like so :

   $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

   3. if you want to determine wether its a user or admin you need to make IF statements and conditions to identity the usernames if they will have privilege to a certain page and add SESSION at the top of the script. [look at this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: While good suggestions, they don't really answer the question of why it doesn't work.